# What is the best way to structure posts for the same event happening in different years?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy

This isn't a code specific question, it's a little more general. 
I have events happening every year and want to have a post for each one. The name should be the same for each year, so the url's would be something like:
domain.com/events/2021/event-name 
domain.com/events/2022/event-name

I initially set this up using a custom post type for 'events' and with a taxonomy for 'year' with the plan of just creating each event and assigning the relevant year.

The problem with this is that I cannot have the same slug more than once so I end up with:
domain.com/events/2021/event-name
domain.com/events/2022/event-name-2

I could create a custom post type for each year, but I feel like that is not a very elegant solution, and would prefer not to have to create a new custom post type every year.

I wondered if anyone can suggest a good approach for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not append the year to the post slug so then you'd have `2021-event-name` and `2020-event-name`?

Comment: ok thanks @TonyDjukic I think it may have to be that way, I just wondered if anyone knew of a different way of doing this so the slugs could be the same.